# i18n routing in Next.js using graphql results in 404 for non default locale

Tags: next.js, internationalization

We are working with GraphQL and NextJS. We try to create paths with the getStaticPaths function. These paths have the right format (see [screenshot of the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyxy6.png)).

The paths work and the correct page is shown for every page with the default locale. If you change to another locale you get a 404.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
const data = await client.query({
    query: allPages
  });
  const paths = data.data.ItemForPage.filter((pagee) =>
    pagee.content.general.path !== null
  ).map((page) => {
      return {
        params: { page: [page.content.general.path], locale : page.language },
      }
  });
console.log("paths",paths);
  return {
    paths : paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

next.config

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'nl'],
    defaultLocale: 'nl',
  }
}
```

We tried by hardcoding two paths, "contact" for "nl" and for "en". If "nl" is the default locale, this page is shown correctly. If we go to the "en" version we get a 404 and vice versa.

I've created a codesandbox reproducing the problem https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/determined-neumann-7sbwmt?file=%2FREADME.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your path is possible a invalid string.
In order to actually let the routing work, your path needs to be a string.

You can achieve this by using backticks:

```
 page: [`${page.content.general.path}`]
```

But that won't fix the actual problem. The reason why only your defaultLocale is working, is because you misplaced a bracket. Your language is currently in the same object of your path, but needs to be in the params object.

Replace your current code with this:

```
params: { page: [`${page.content.general.path}`] }, locale: page.language,
```

Your code should look something like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const data = await client.query({
    query: allPages
  });

  const paths = data.data.TideItemForPage.filter((pagee) =>
    pagee.content.general.path !== null

  ).map((page) => {
    return {
      params: { page: [`${page.content.general.path}`] }, locale: page.language,
    }
  });
  console.log("paths", paths.map((path) => path.params))
  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}
```

You can read more about this on:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing